# Globally accessible user object in controllers and models

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a Laravel API which authenticates users using an authentication token. For any routes that need authentication, I'm wrapping them in an `auth` filter:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::get('user/account', 'UserController@getAccountDetails');
});
```

My `auth` filter basically decrypts the passed in authentication token and checks if it's valid:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    // Try catch because Crypt::decrypt throws an exception if it's not a valid string to decrypt
    try {
        $authToken = Crypt::decrypt(Request::header('Authorization'));

        // If there's a user tied to this auth token, it's valid
        $user = AuthToken::where('token', '=', $authToken)->first()->user()->first();

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \Exception();
        }

        // Make the user globally accessible in controllers

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return Response::json([
            'data' => [
                'error' => 'You must be logged in to access this resource.'
            ],
            'success' => false,
            'status' => 403
        ], 403);
    }
});
```

Pretty simple stuff, but I'm stuck on the next part. I want to be able to easily retrieve the current user record in my controllers and models.

For example, if I used Laravel's `Auth` library I could get the current user by doing `Auth::user()` in my controllers. I'd like to have that kind of functionality but I'm not sure how to build it. Could I write a class that gets instantiated after authentication with a static method that returns a `User` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's an option for you, but maybe you would like to use oauth2 instead of writing "your own" token based authentication?

There is quite nice ouath2 server wrapper for laravel project: oauth2-server-laravel.

According to it's documentation you can (for example for password flow authentication) put this in it's config:

```
'password' => array(
'class'            => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\Password',
'access_token_ttl' => 604800,
'callback'         => function($username, $password){

    $credentials = array(
        'email' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
    );

    $valid = Auth::validate($credentials);

    if (!$valid) {
        return false;
    }

    return Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($credentials)->id;
}
)
```

And than you can you can authenticate (via username and password in that case) sending post request like that:

```
POST https://www.example.com/oauth/access_token?
grant_type=password&
client_id=the_client_id&
client_secret=the_client_secret&
username=the_username&
password=the_password&
scope=scope1,scope2&
state=123456789
```

Request will return generated token, and then you can make api calls as usual, just putting the token in the post data.

In your api logic getting the user by token is quite simple in that case, just run:

`User::find(ResourceServer::getOwnerId());`

It will makes stuff like: refresh tokens, other grant flows, scope access, clients management a lot easier. Out of the box in fact.

You can also secure any particular route like that:

```
Route::get('secure-route', array('before' => 'oauth', function(){
    return "oauth secured route";
}));
```

You can find more details in oauth2-server-laravel documentation: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

And oauth2 documentation: http://oauth.net/documentation/

Comment: No problem, just been doing the same thing and thought it may help you too. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the `Auth::user()` method is quite convenient. So, why not simply extend the `Auth` class to write your own authentication driver ? You can find all needed doc [here](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#authentication).

You can then just use the `Auth` facade just like in every other laravel app you could write… wonderful, isn't it ?